# message does not appear when sending email to other than gmail

Tags: php, email

I am having a problem sending an email to the following domains:

```
@yahoo.com,
@hotmail.com, and
@mncgroup.com
```

using the PHP mail() function. But there's no problem if I send an email to @gmail.com

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
$to = "$email";
 $subject = "[NO-REPLY]Confirmation Account Pengaduan Keluhan I-news Tv";   

 $header = "From: inewsit@mncgroup.com  \r\n";

 $header .= "Akun Information MNC Biro";

 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

 $message = "<!DOCTYPE html>
              <html>
              <head>
                <title></title>
              </head>
              <body>
              <h1>Selamat Akun Anda Sudah Aktif</h1>
              <p>Detail Account Username :</p>
              <br>Your username :  $hasil[username]
              <br> Your Full Name :  $hasil[nama] 
              <br> Your Email Address : $hasil[email]
              <br> Your Status Akun :  $status_akun1
              <br> Your Lever authentication : $hasil[level]
              <br> Your Register Date : $hasil[tanggal_register]
              <br>Login sekarang ke : <a href='http://mncgroup.hol.es'><i>http://mncgroup.hol.es</i></a>
              </body>
              </html>";

 $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);

 if( $retval == true ) {
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
          <a class="panel-close close" data-dismiss="alert">x</a>
        <center>Silahkan Cek <strong>Email</strong> Anda</center>
    </div>
 <?php
```

when i run this code and i try to send email to 3 domain above, the message does not get into the email

Answer (score 0):

First, try this in your code:

```
echo (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) ? 'Message sent!' : 'Message not sent!';
```

Because of `mail()` function returns `true or false` depending on whether the mail was accepted for delivery. I recommend you check your spam folder at those addresses. I have heard that mail sent from the free servers due to the amount of abuse goes directly to spam.

**Try** this sample code for checking purpose:

```
<?php 
    $to = 'ANY EMAIL@yahoo.com'; 
    $subject = 'ANY SUBJECT'; 
    $message = 'ANY MESSAGE'; 
    $headers = 'From: check@check.com' . "\r\n" . 
        'Reply-To: no-reply@check@check.com' . "\r\n" . 
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 

    echo (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) ? 'Message sent!' : 'Message not sent!'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all occurrences of `\r\n` with PHP_EOL. Something like this:

```
$to = "$email";
$eol = PHP_EOL;
$subject = "[NO-REPLY]Confirmation Account Pengaduan Keluhan I-news Tv";   

$header = "From: inewsit@mncgroup.com  $eol";

$header .= "Akun Information MNC Biro";

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0$eol";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1$eol";
```

See if that changes anything.